# Postgis Functional Index on st_pointonsurface() Ignored

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-index, postgis-2.2

If I define the following table...

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_vast_importance(
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)
);
CREATE INDEX ON tbl_vast_importance USING GIST (geom);
CREATE INDEX ON tbl_vast_importance USING GIST (st_pointonsurface(geom));
```

...and run the following query

```
SELECT

  id,
  geom

FROM

  tbl_vast_importance a
  JOIN tbl_vast_importance b ON (st_intersects(st_pointonsurface(a.geom),b.geom))

WHERE

  a.id != b.id
```

...the spatial index is not used; yet using st_intersects() on the geometry directly results in the geometry index being used properly. How do I force Postgres to use the proper index for st_pointonsurface()? It would be wasteful to create an explicit centroid column for this purpose.

Explain Results:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..1034058179737.31 rows=609220605748 width=784)
  Join Filter: ((a.id <> b.id) AND st_intersects(st_pointonsurface(a.geom), b.geom))
  ->  Seq Scan on tbl_vast_importance a  (cost=0.00..78073.11 rows=1351911 width=392)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..153484.67 rows=1351911 width=392)
        ->  Seq Scan on tbl_vast_importance b  (cost=0.00..78073.11 rows=1351911 width=392)
Planning time: 0.188 ms
```

postgis_full_version = `"POSTGIS="2.2.0dev r12887" GEOS="3.5.0dev-CAPI-1.9.0 r3995" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.0, released 2014/04/16" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11.99" TOPOLOGY RASTER"`

Comment: It seems you are intersecting a point with a point in the above query. How many results do you expect that to return? What does your explain show. Also, worth noting, that ST_PointonSurface and ST_Centroid are not necessarily [the same](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76498/how-is-st-pointonsurface-calculated).

Comment: The actual table I am using contains millions of rows and is being joined with itself with st_intersects(geom,pointonsurface), but I have tested this against various tables and seemingly under no circumstances is the index ever used. I know pointonsurface is not always a centroid, but is more concise than centermost_possible_point_within_polygon. Index should work the same on either function.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly and what does your explain show -- you seem to be trying to find where a point intersects the centroid of a geometry?

Comment: I edited it to be more clear, I'm actually intersecting the centroid of the geometry with the MultiPolygon of the same table

Comment: I added explain results to the question

Comment: What happens if you run it like this `WITH pointonsurface (geom) AS (SELECT ST_PointOnSurface(geom) as geom FROM tbl_vast_importance)
SELECT id, geom FROM tbl_vast_importance a, pointonsurface b 
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);` Functions inside where clauses confuse the optimizer and you query will then be viewed as a cartesian join, as the explain output suggests. Seeing as you have to scan the table completely and calculate a point on surface, moving this into a CTE, means the values will now be considered as constants.

Comment: I'm working on a similar problem, with even bigger tables, and I have had order of magnitude improvements just by rewritting queries as above. So, please humor, me, I'd be very interested if that rewrite makes any difference.

Comment: It did work,  but would be nice to avoid the extra cte. Its odd that postgres can't figure out that it needs to use the index

Comment: Not really, just because you are using a function in the Where does not translate into the query optimizer realizing you have a functional index built on same function. The same argument holds for ST_Buffer or anything you might put in the Where. Did it decrease query time dramatically?

Comment: Also, it isn't really an extra CTE, you are doing that calculation either way when you run ST_PointOnSurface in the WHERE, so no extra work is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)` uses the index while `ST_Intersects(ST_PointOnsurface(a.geom),b.geom))` does not is because while ST_Intersects will always use an index, if available, performing a bounding box test first, ie, &&, there is no way to know what the result of ST_PointOnSurface will be, so the optimizer no longer regards this as something to automatically apply an index to, based on pre-existing geometry bounding boxes -- as your EXPLAIN shows. The fact that your index uses the same function name is irrelevant -- one is a functional mapping of values to an index, the other a function call (that has no knowledge of any indexes on tables). You could observe similar behaviour from ST_Buffer or any other function that alters a geometry in a WHERE clause containing a statement that would normally use an index automatically.

If you rewrite your query so that ST_PointOnSurface is first calculated in a CTE (which involves no extra processing time, as you are calculating it anyway in your WHERE clause), then the index will be seen by the planner.

```
WITH pointonsurface (geom) AS 
  (SELECT 
      ST_PointOnSurface(geom) as geom 
   FROM tbl_vast_importance)
SELECT 
     id, geom 
FROM tbl_vast_importance a, pointonsurface b 
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);
```

In my experience, rewriting queries in this way, so that any functions are calculated outside or any WHERE clauses or sub queries, can lead to order of magnitude increases in query time (due to avoiding table scans).

Answer (score 3):

You can force it by manually adding a `&&` (bounding box intersection) condition in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  
  id,
  geom
FROM tbl_vast_importance a
  JOIN tbl_vast_importance b
    ON a.geom && b.geom AND ST_Intersects(ST_PointOnSurface(a.geom),b.geom)
WHERE a.id != b.id
```