# How is the Point on surface tool calculated in QGIS

Tags: qgis, centroids, mathematics, surface

I am interested to know how the [Point on surface](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgispointonsurface) tool works in QGIS 3. I am choosing to use this rather than the [Centroids](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgiscentroids) tool which works of the "center of mass" methodology because this creates a point outside the area of the polygon which is not suitable for my needs.

The QGIS documentation does not seem to explain the calculation used but I would like to know so I can test whether it is suitable for my analysis and so I can incorporate an error with my calculations.

Comment: It's an open source tool, so you just need to start digging. Most labeling points are calculated from the midpoint of a transect, so some clever test cases can often locate the transfers.

Comment: check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76498/how-is-st-pointonsurface-calculated) excellent (empirical) answer

Comment: Both the linked answer with its comment (PostGIS) and this post (QGIS) are relying on GEOS, so it is the same algorithm.